# django can't find full url but can find path

Tags: django

I've got gulp working with django, and I'm trying to serve everything from my `myapp/static/myapp/` folder.   I'm using the shell to troubleshoot and for some reason the resolver can find the path but not the full url.

```
#enter shell with:
# > ./venv/Scripts/python ./myapp/manage.py shell

import django.urls as urls
import os

#no port
urls.resolve('http://localhost/static/myapp/favicon/site.webmanifest.json')
urls.resolve('http://127.0.0.1/static/myapp/favicon/site.webmanifest.json')

#django dev server port

urls.resolve('http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/myapp/favicon/site.webmanifest.json')
urls.resolve('http://localhost/static/myapp/favicon/site.webmanifest.json')

#browsersync port
urls.resolve('http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/myapp/favicon/site.webmanifest.json')    
urls.resolve('http://localhost:3000/static/myapp/favicon/site.webmanifest.json')

#all the above produce an error like below
#output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 25, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'path': path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'path': 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/myapp/favicon/site.webmanifest.json'}
############################################################################################

# now if I resolve with just the path:
urls.resolve('/static/myapp/favicon/site.webmanifest.json')

##output
ResolverMatch(func=django.views.static.serve, args=(), kwargs={'path': 'myapp/favicon/site.webmanifest.json', 'document_root': 'C:\\Users\\jmarshall\\source\\myapp\\myapp\\../static'}, url_name=None, app_names=[], namespaces=[], route=^static/(?P<path>.*)$)
############################################################################################

m = urls.resolve('/static/myapp/favicon/site.webmanifest.json')
os.path.exists(os.path.join(m.kwargs['document_root'], m.kwargs['path']))

##output
True
############################################################################################
```

On the front end, the static files are most certainly 404.  Any idea what's happening?

I guess I should also mention I have my urls set like:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

from the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Comment: You just have improperly configured static files,  show us file structure and your configuration instead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[resolve()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) just resolves path as documented

> The resolve() function can be used for resolving **URL paths** to the
> corresponding view functions.

even if it is resolved to static view that does not necessarily mean that path is found by configured staticfile finders afterwards , by default your file must reside inside STATICFILES_DIRS as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)

Comment: I was purposely not using the myapp/myapp/static folder tying to force use of the myapp/static folder.  Your point stands though that my test with `resolve` was misusing the function.  shucks.